# Too many redirect with pagination query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect pages

From:
`mysite.com/cata/catb`

To `mysite.com/cata/catb?p=1`

But it is ending up with so many p=1

i.e `mysite.com/cata/catb?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1?p=1`

My .htaccess is

```
redirect 301 ^/cata/catb$ /cata/catb?p=1
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is redirecting `/cats/catb` to the same directory/file that is why you are getting the loop error. To fix this, you need to use mod-rewrite  and a `RewriteCond` that excludes the destination Query String.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=1$
RewriteRule ^cata/catb/?$ /cata/catb?p=1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, It works bur partly. i.e when I add more lines for other categories, they don't work. Only the first one work. I can however copy `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=1$` before each category to make it work. There must be a nicer way. Basically all I wanted is all my `/catA/catB` page to redirect to `/catA/catB?p=1`
Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, I got one more issue. All the other pagination page also redirecting to `p=1`. I understand why but don't know how to fix :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that your `redirect 301 ^/cata/catb$ /cata/catb?p=1` redirect regex applies only on the path path of your URL and ignores your ending parameters `?p=1`

Therefore the redirection is done in a kind of recursively manner:

```
/cata/catb →　/cata/catb?p=1
/cata/catb?p=1　→　/cata/catb?p=1?p=1
/cata/catb?p=1?p=1　→　/cata/catb?p=1?p=1?p=1
...
```

Could you try changing your

`redirect 301 ^/cata/catb$ /cata/catb?p=1` in `redirect 301 ^/cata/catb$ /cata/catc?p=1` and check the output?

or adding a trailing `"/"`to your path -> `/cata/catb/?p=1` even if it is far from being sexy.

You might also be interested by the following commands `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteEngine on`:

https://superuser.com/questions/155139/htaccess-301-redirect-with-regular-expressions

Good luck!